Confusion on the domains of local flow for defining Lie derivative
Hi I am self studying Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. Given the definition

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold, $V$ is a smooth vector field on $M$, and $\theta$ is the flow of $V$. For any smooth vector field $W$ on $M$, define a rough vector field on $M$, denoted by $\mathscr{L}_V W$ and called the Lie derivative of $W$ with respect to $V$, by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\mathscr{L}_V W\right)_p & =\left.\frac{d}{d t}\right|_{t=0} d\left(\theta_{-t}\right)_{\theta_t(p)}\left(W_{\theta_t(p)}\right) \\
& =\lim _{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{d\left(\theta_{-t}\right)_{\theta_t(p)}\left(W_{\theta_t(p)}\right)-W_p}{t},
\end{aligned}
$$
provided the derivative exists. For small $t \neq 0$, at least the difference quotient makes sense: $\theta_t$ is defined in a neighborhood of $p$, and $\theta_{-t}$ is the inverse of $\theta_t$, so both $d\left(\theta_{-t}\right)_{\theta_t(p)}\left(W_{\theta_t(p)}\right)$ and $W_p$ are elements of $T_p M$.

I am confused with the domains and codomains for $\theta_t$ and $\theta_{-t}$ since they are only locally defined. Did their domains change when $t$ change?

By the definition of local flow via solutions to the PDE $\dot{\theta}(p,t)=W_{\theta(p,t)}$ (erpressed in some local chart), if the solution exists for the initial value $\theta(p,0)=p$ at the time t, then it exists for the initial value $\theta(\theta(p,t),0)=\theta(p,t)$ at time $-t$.
You can think of it as flowing backwards along the path or reversing time.
Now you fix $t$ and obtain a local diffeomorphism from some (open) subset of $M$ to another. The map for the parameter $-t$ is the inverse of that map. So yes, your domain and codomain chance. But the expression of the pullback of $W$ along the flow has the correct base points.

Thank you for the answer. I am trying to understand it. The limit invokes different $\theta$ at different time makes me hesitated.

You have to distinguish what the parameter $t$ means with respect to maps and points. $\theta_{-t}=\theta(.,-t)$ is a map on an open neighborhood of $\theta_t(p)=\theta(p,t)$. It maps this point to $\theta_0(p) = p$. So if you push the tangent vector $W_{\theta(p,t)}$ via the differential, you obtain a tangent vector at $p$ and you can calculate the difference to $W_p$.
